# dlsym returns an invalid pointer

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, dynamic-linking, dlopen

I have a dynamically linked module like so:

```
int func() {
    return 5;
}

extern int(*func_p)() = func;
```

And a main function that loads the function pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main() {
    void *module = dlopen("/tmp/mod/mod.so", RTLD_NOW);
    if (!module)
  {
     printf("Cannot load module: %s\n", dlerror());
     return 1;
  }

    typedef int(*func_f)();
    func_f func;

    func = dlsym(module, "func_p");
    char *error = dlerror();
    if (error)
{
   printf("Cannot find init in module: %s\n", error);
   return 1;
}

    printf("Func returns: %i\n", func());
}
```

Is there any way I can make this work or is this completely out of bounds?

Could I manually "resolve" the function pointer?

Comment: What have you tried? The code you posted here doesn't compile, for a few reasons. (`num` isn't defined, for example.) But if you fix those errors, this more or less works. Also, what do you mean "manually resolve" the function pointer? That's the whole point of `dlsym`, to resolve it for you by name.

Comment: Sorry, I trimmed the code a bit when composing the post and missed some stuff. Fixed now

Comment: If you replace `dlsym(module, "func_p")` with `dlsym(module, "func")` it works

Comment: Why are you using `dlsym` to look up `func_p` when you apparently want `func`? Just look up `func`. Do you think it is not externally visible or something? It should be, unless you took steps during linking to make it not visible. If so, then you can look up `func_p`, but that gets you the address a pointer to `func`, so you need to dereference it to get the address of `func`.

Comment: This is a simplified version of a problem I have. func_p is already dereferenced by it's definition.

Comment: @Rillian: I'm not completely sure what you mean by "`func_p` is already dereferenced by its definition," but I think you're being confused by an odd corner case in C. It's true that `func_p()` implicitly dereferences `func_p`, making it unnecessary to write `(*func_p)()`. (But the implicit dereference is in the context of its use, not its definition.) But `dlsym` does not return the *value* of the symbol you look up. It returns it's *address*. In other words, what `dysym` returns is not `func_p` but rather `&func_p`. And `(&func_p)()` is not a legal function call.

Comment: Your post does not state what problem you have implementing this. Some things have been pointed out in the comments, but you need to update the post to describe a specific problem and to ask a specific question. A specific problem would be something like “`dlsym` returns a null pointer” or “I tried calling a function at the address `dlsym` returned, and the program crash.” And it should have complete specific code for the case that failed.

Comment: I've taken your advice and changed the title

Comment: rici I'm not too sure to be honest. If I had defined the function pointer correctly then func_p and func should be identical and they're not. That's all I know. I suspect this has something to do with the fact that I'm initialisating an extern variable?

Comment: @rillian: the *value* of `func_p` is the *address* of `func`. The *address* of `func_p` is the address of a pointer-sized block of bytes where the *value* of `func_p` is stashed. Since `func_p` is not `*const`, its value might be modified. I suppose you don't do that, but you could and the compiler certainly can't tell that you won't.

Comment: "then func_p and func should be identical". No, they should not, and they are not. `func` is a function, `func_p` is a function pointer. These are interchangeable in certain contexts, but not all. For example, `func()` and `func_p()` do the same thing, but `&func` and `&func_p` are very different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, `func` is a function, and `func_p` is a pointer to a function. When a name is given as an argument to `dlsym`, `dlsym` returns the address of the named thing. So, for `"func"`, it returns the address of the function named `func`. For `"func_p"`, it returns the address of the pointer named `func_p`.

Of course, the address of the pointer `func_p` cannot be used to call the function. For that, you need the value of the pointer.

Either of these should work:

```
// Get address of function.
int (*func)() = (int (*)()) dlsym(module, "func");

// Call function.
func();
```

```
// Get address of pointer to function.
int (**p)() = dlsym(module, "func_p");

// Deference to get pointer to function, then call function.
(*p)();
```

The latter is unnecessary unless the function is not externally visible. As long as `func` can be looked up by `dlsym`, the former should suffice.

Also note that documentation about linkers and related things, possibly `dlsym`, refers to the values of symbols, but, for these kinds of symbols, those values are the addresses where the things the symbols refer to are. That is, for C, `func` is a function and `func_p` is a pointer, but, for the linker, `func` is some name it found in an object module, and its “value” is the address where it will be in memory, and similarly the value of `func_p` is the address where it will be. When reading such documentation, you have to be mindful the linkers and symbol resolvers are performing different tasks and treating names differently than C compilers do.

Comment: Thank you very much. The second example works for me. However the first does not and is also exactly what I did in my original question where it was obscured by a typedef. Could you edit it before I can mark it as complete

Comment: I understand the second one, you're getting a pointer to a pointer to a function, dereferencing it once and calling the resulting function pointer. So the reason the first one does not work must be because you're calling a pointer to a function pointer.

Comment: @RillianGrant: The first code works, except that a compiler may require a cast for the conversion. I updated to include a cast. I know it works because I built and executed it. If it does not work for you, you need to provide information about the problem encountered. The code is not calling a pointer to a function pointer; it calls a function by pointer, which is the only way to call a function. (When you try to call a function by name, the function designator is automatically converted to a pointer.)